# iptables-restore command failed in iptables v1.4.16.2

Tags: networking, iptables

I am currently have *iptables v1.4.16.2*  installed. 
when I try to run iptables-restore command for the following set of rules

> *filter
>
> -I FORWARD 1 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -o vlan2753 -j DROP -m conntrack --ctstate NEW
>
> -I FORWARD 2 -s 10.10.0.0/16 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -o vlan2753 -j DROP -m conntrack --ctstate NEW
>
> COMMIT

It fails with **'iptables-restore: line 4 failed'**

But, the same set  of rules work fine, if set in machine having *iptables v1.4.9*.

Can anyone help out in figuring out what has changed in two versions and what I need to change to make it work. I am very new to using iptables commands.

Answer (score 0):

is this generated by iptables-save?
how about you try this instead for iptables-restore:

```
*filter
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/16 -o vlan2753 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o vlan2753 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
COMMIT
```

worked for me ;)